# Cloudfront Path pattern issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a AWS S3 bucket with directory structure with each user in my application having a seperate director like `Dir(User-ID) eg Dir(1233233)`. I want to create 2 cloudfront path patter such that -

1. The images(png and jpg) just inside the parent directory should be accessible without a signed url (should be public).
2. All other sub-directories and files should require a signed url (should be private).

I am trying to create something like `Dir(*)/*.jpg` with unsigned policy and a default one with a signed policy. This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

'(' is not an acceptable character and will not work with patterns.

Checked on,

> Dir*/*.jpg

and it works.

Based on the documentation,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern

The maximum length of a path pattern is 255 characters. The value can contain any of the following characters:

> A-Z, a-z
>
> Path patterns are case sensitive, so the path pattern *.jpg doesn't
>   apply to the file LOGO.JPG.
>
> 0-9
>
> _ - . * $ / ~ " ' @ : +
>
> &, passed and returned as & amp;

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will Dir*/*.jpg give access to all the .jpg's in all the sub-directories too? I don't want it to give access to the sub-directories.

Comment: Try with allowed characters. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Yes I will try with allowed characters, just wanted to know if the pattern you suggested Dir*/*.jpg blocks the subdirectory access.